SwiftData Can't Use PhotosPickerItem as Property
I'm trying to find a way to reference photos in the User Photos Library and add those references in a SwiftData record. I can, of course, get the photos from the library, convert to Data type and store that in SwiftData, but I'm trying to avoid duplicating all that data (there will be a lot of photos). I thought I should be able to get a URL for a Photos item, but have not found any way to do that. I tried making a property in the SwiftData model for [PhotosPickerItem] but that fails with the error: "Referencing instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' on 'Array' requires that 'PhotosPickerItem' conform to 'PersistentModel'"  in the model initializer.
The idea of the model:
@Model
final public class Thing {
    
    var name: String = ""
    var comment: String = ""
    var photoPickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []

    init(name: String, comment: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.comment = comment
    }
}//class

And then in the picker view:
struct ImagePickerView: View {
    @Binding var selectedImageURLs: [URL]
    @State private var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    
    var thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems, maxSelectionCount: 5,           matching: .images, photoLibrary: .shared()) {
            Text("Select Images")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItems) { oldItems, newItems in
            Task {
                thing.photoPickerItems = []
                for item in newItems {
                    thing.photoPickerItems.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

I would appreciate any guidance on a way to accomplish the idea. Xcode 15.4, iOS 17.5

Note, AFAIK Photos library is a database, it is not just a collection of files on disk, so you cannot get the url or path of each photo because they do not exist.
You may want to look at PhotoKit
to access the library and retrieve a particular photo.
That is, store some sort of photo id or name
in SwiftData, then use PhotoKit.

Thanks. I'll check it out. I changed the model of Thing like this:
var photoPickerItems: [String] = []
and in the .onChange I append item.itemIdentifier
I can then get a PHAsset from that item.itemIdentifier and re-create the image. The problem is that the itemIdentifiers do indeed seem to be "local". Running the app on two devices with the same Apple ID still results in two identifiers. Since I intend to sync via iCloud, clearly this won't work.

You can’t rely on data owned by another app, you have no idea what happens to those images and the state of your stored data would always be uncertain. Maybe the best way forward is to store a smaller version of the image in your app.
